# SQL "LIKE" selector works like "=" in my search engine

Tags: php, search-engine

I have created a simple search engine to display results from database,but i need it to display all results with similar characters in them,not the whole exact word.Soo for example user types eng-- it should return result engine and all other words with eng in them,but at the moment it will return something only when you type whole word,engine.Guess i have a mistake somewhere but cannot really find it:There is my code.

```
<?php

$fsearch = "";
if (!empty($_GET['fsearch'])){

$fsearch=$_GET['fsearch'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM food_data_bg WHERE ";
$terms = explode (" ",$fsearch);
$i=0;
foreach($terms as $each){
      $i++;
     if($i == 1){
       $query .= "title LIKE '$each'";
     }
else{
      $query .= "OR title LIKE '$each'";
     }
}

     $hostname = "localhost";
     $username = "name";
     $password = "pass";
     $databaseName = "dbName";
     $connect = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
     $connect->set_charset("utf8");
       $query = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

       $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
          if($num_rows > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
               $title = $row["title"];
               $fimage = $row["fimage"];
               $carbs = $row["carbohydrates"];
               $fats = $row["fats"];
               $proteins = $row["proteins"];
               $CaloriesTotal = $row["calories total"];
              echo "
                    <table id='table1'>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class='Table1-row2'>
                    <td><a><img src='$fimage'</a></td>
                    <td>$title</td>
                    <td>$carbs</td>
                    <td>$fats</td>
                    <td>$proteins</td>
                    <td>$CaloriesTotal</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>";
                    }
                 } //got "else" claim here,but i don't think the mistake is in it...
             }
?>
```

Any help,advice is appreciated <3 Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE has to include wildcards if you want it to behave properly. So if you're looking for that word in the string, you could do something like this...

```
$query .= "title LIKE '%".$each."%'";
```

The percent (%) will match with anything (zero or more characters of any kind).

Comment: Woah i Knew it was something easy,but didn't know that was a sign for Match with anything,Thanks thats exactly what i needed <3 Will accept it in 7 mins

Comment: There are some other options, but percent means zero or more characters, so it'll find the word at the beginning or end of the string as well. Here are some more... https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_wildcards.asp